# upload function in cakephp, how to get the url

Tags: cakephp, upload

i have had this function to upload files to webroot/attach/ :

```
   public function upload(){

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($_FILES["file"]["name"]){
    $allowedExts = array("torrent");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__("Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />" . 
     "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />" . 
     "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />"
    ));
    if (file_exists("../webroot/attach/torrents/" ."3alany_com_". $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    $this->Session->setFlash(__($_FILES["file"]["name"] . " موجود قبل كده يا بوب "));   
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../webroot/attach/torrents/"."3alany_com_". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        $filename = "3alany_com_". $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
        $user_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
        mysql_set_charset('utf8');

    $this->Attachment->query("INSERT INTO attachments (
                filename ,  type , size , user_id
                ) VALUES (
                '{$filename}' , 'torrent', '{$filesize}' , '$user_id' 
                );");

    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    $this->Session->setFlash(__(" موجود قبل كده يا بوب ")); 
      }
    }
    }else
      {
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    $this->Session->setFlash(__("أمتداد الفايل مش مقبول")); 
      }
    }


#############IMAGE

if ($_FILES["image"]["name"])
{
if (file_exists("../webroot/attach/images/" ."3alany_com_". $_FILES["image"]["name"]))
{
    $this->Session->setFlash(__($_FILES["image"]["name"] . " موجود قبل كده يا بوب "));  
}
else
{

$uploadedfile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$boss = explode(".", strtolower($file_name));
$extension = strtolower(end($boss)); 
$array = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'); 
if (!in_array($extension, $array))
{
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    $this->Session->setFlash(__("أمتداد الفايل مش مقبول")); 
}
$size = filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
if ($size > 10000000)
{
echo "الصوره المضاعه كبيره";
exit;
}
if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg")
{
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
} else
if ($extension == "png")
{
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
} else
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadedfile); 
if ($width < 685)
{
$newwidth = $width;
} else
{
$newwidth = 500;
};
$newheight = ($height / $width) * $newwidth;
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

$filename = "../webroot/attach/images/". "3alany_com_" . $file_name;
imagejpeg($tmp, $filename, 100);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);

        mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    $filename = "3alany_com_". $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
    $user_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
    $this->Attachment->query("INSERT INTO attachments (
                filename ,  type , size , user_id
                ) VALUES (
                '{$filename}' , 'image', '{$filesize}' , '$user_id' 
                );");


$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
$this->Session->setFlash(__(" موجود قبل كده يا بوب ")); 

      }

}




}
}
```

but my problem is how to get this files with a like, i have tried many ways like :

> Html->url('/attach/torrents/' .
>   $p['Attachment']['filename'], true); ?>

but it didn't work, it's give me " Error: AttachController could not be found."

so how can i handle this thing, thanks :) !

ps:i have cake 2

Answer (score 0):

look at the global constants of cakephp:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html

Comment: thanks, it's good now, but i have a little problem, that the flash Session can not display just the fist flash Session display and others don't ! what do you think is the problem ?

Comment: Do you want to display multiple messages flash at the same time? This is not possible with the basic components of CakePHP, need to work on your Session component. Search in the network a few examples.

In short, you need to create a setFlash method able to record more than one message.